# How to rotate and merge mp4 videos with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have two videos test.mp4 and test2.mp4, can i rotate video's then merge with one ffmpeg command ?

I can do that separate

For example I rotate videos wirh this command

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter_complex transpose=1 test_rotate.mp4
```

And merge with this command

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i c:/ffmpeg/merge.txt -codec copy output.mp4
```

But when I want to use them together it says "Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together"

Comment: I think it's not possible. First rotate, then merge.

Comment: thanks for your answer but if you have more than 3-4 videos it will be problem

Comment: Are you using ffmepg manually ? or using code or script ?

Comment: I am using ffmpeg in android application , I get videos that are rotated by 90 degrees. I must fix all videos rotation then merge. Problem is it will took a long time if I do that separate.

Comment: I think you should fix the rotation problem in your android app rather than trying to rotate it externally. Using ffmpeg is bad practice, it looses video quality and sometimes sound issues, in addition to it's poor performance.